# Magento: Tier Pricing 'Bug' in bundle.js for "Price as Configured" on Bundle products

Tags: javascript, php, magento

Am having a little difficulty figuring out how to get the "Price as Configured" part of a Bundle page to update with the tier pricing.

Right now, if I have a checkbox selection in a bundle product and I click the checkbox to add it to the bundle, the "Price as Configured" updates with the full price for the product rather than the tier pricing (the default quantity for the selection is within the tier pricing realm).

Right now I'm going through the /skin/frontend/base/default/js/bundle.js file and under the selectionPrice method I see the following:

```
selectionPrice: function(optionId, selectionId) {

.................

    if (this.config.priceType == '0') {
        price = this.config.options[optionId].selections[selectionId].price;
        tierPrice = this.config.options[optionId].selections[selectionId].tierPrice;

        for (var i=0; i < tierPrice.length; i++) {
            if (Number(tierPrice[i].price_qty) <= qty && Number(tierPrice[i].price) <= price) {
                price = tierPrice[i].price;
            }
        }
    } else {
        selection = this.config.options[optionId].selections[selectionId];
        if (selection.priceType == '0') {
            price = selection.priceValue;
        } else {
            price = (this.config.basePrice*selection.priceValue)/100;
        }
    }
```

So far I can tell that it gets to setting:

```
price = this.config.options[optionId].selections[selectionId].price
```

Now normally if tierPrice returns an object it should be able to iterate through it and find the tier price (at least that's what the code seems to be suppose to do).  However, it never enters the for loop that would actually set a tier price.  In the console I can access the tier price directly by doing:

```
bundle.config.options['301'].selections['1066'].tierPrice['32000-5']
```

However, the Magento code is dependant on being able to call .....tierPrice[0] rather than ....tierPrice['32000-5'] to get each individual tier pricing object.  Calling ....tierPrice[0] returns undefined and tierPrice.length returns undefined.

Why can't I access the nested arrays using a for loop?  What are my options here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an alternative to the JavaScript based solutions that unfortunately require a replacement of the core file `bundle.js` I have a PHP based solution

The problem in the first place is that this object should not be an object at all. We can intervene in the JSON generation and make sure that it actually is an array.

For this, the class `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type_Price` has to be rewritten with the following method override:

```
public function getTierPrice($qty = null, $product)
{
    $tierPrice = parent::getTierPrice($qty, $product);
    if (is_array($tierPrice)) {
        return array_values($tierPrice);
    }
    return $tierPrice;
}
```

The `getTierPrice()` method is not used anywhere, where the string keys would be relevant as far as I can see, so this is more elegant than taking the generated JSON apart and recreating it.

I wrote a little extension that fixes this together with another bundle tier pricing bug, you can get it from https://github.com/sgh-it/bundletierprices

**Further reading:** http://www.schmengler-se.de/en/2014/10/magento-buendelprodukte-staffelpreise-der-einfachen-produkte-nutzen/

Comment: In a strange turn of events I've actually just come across the second problem your module addresses (with tier pricing in bundles) and am now using it to solve that issue after a Google search brought me back to this thread.  Nice work!

Answer (score 0):

I am primarily using Magento 1.7 and:

[Skip to the update below for the meat of my answer. Summary: *What did we learn? I think you are using Magento 1.5. But even Magento 1.7 is not good enough. The features you are trying to use are not fully bug-fixed until Magento 1.8.*]

I set out to help you here because I know how complex working with bundles can be. I haven't used tier pricing so I set that up on my development server and started stepping through the `bundle.js` functions that you listed above.

I have found two things that confuse me:

a) My `tierPrice[]` *is* an array with indexes 0,1,2 (I set up three tiers via the Magento admin):
[image: tierPrice object is an array object]

Here to help you is a snippet from my bundle JSON object definition, that is, from `app/design/frontend/themename/default/template/bundle/catalog/product/view/type/bundle/bundle.phtml`

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
  //<![CDATA[
      var bundle = new Product.Bundle(<?php echo $this->getJsonConfig() ?>);
  //]]>
 </script>
```

Snippet:

```
var bundle = new Product.Bundle({"options":{"837":{"selections":{"4205":{"qty":1,"customQty":"1","price":52,"priceInclTax":52,"priceExclTax":52,"priceValue":0,"priceType":"0","tierPrice":[{"price_id":"4","website_id":"0","all_groups":"1","cust_group":32000,"price":29.99,"price_qty":"2.0000","website_price":"29.9900"},{"price_id":"5","website_id":"0","all_groups":"1","cust_group":32000,"price":18.88,"price_qty":"3.0000","website_price":"18.8800"},{"price_id":"6","website_id":"0","all_groups":"1","cust_group":32000,"price":7.77,"price_qty":"4.0000","website_price":"7.7700"}], ...
```

Does yours look like this?

b) So on my development server after the for loop above, `bundle.js` has correctly identified a tier price *but* later in the code the variable price gets reset based on displaying price including tax or excluding tax, ie this code:

```
//file: skin/frontend/theme/default/js/bundle.js
//function: selectionPrice()
//...
selection = this.config.options[optionId].selections[selectionId];
if (selection.priceInclTax !== undefined) {
    priceInclTax = selection.priceInclTax;
    price = selection.priceExclTax !== undefined ? selection.priceExclTax : selection.price;
} else {
    priceInclTax = price;
}
//...
```

Therefore, in the end, my 'price as configured' ends up **incorrect** too.

What do you think? Can you figure out why your bundle object is making `tierPrice['32000-5']` instead of `tierPrice[0]`? Is your tier price overwritten when `bundle.js` tries to apply display price including tax or excluding tax?

(And there seems to be no default way of knowing if the tierPrice is including tax or excluding tax. I smell a bug here).

Actually this bug report might be of interest to you.http://www.magentocommerce.com/bug-tracking/issue?issue=11477 (requires login)] and there are [some other bugs tracked on tier pricing](http://www.magentocommerce.com/bug-tracking/search_result/?show_result=1&keywords=tierPrice) which would help explain the code updates in Magento 1.8

**UPDATE: I have been referring to bundle.js from Magento 1.7**

I can see in Magento 1.8 bundle.js has been improved to take into account tierPrice and tierPrice including and excluding tax - but that must also be accompanied by a different bundle JSON object (to hold the fields and values for `tierPrice[i].priceInclTax;` and `tierPrice[i].priceExclTax;`)

So, we might have an answer now:

a) Upgrade to Magento 1.8

or

b) Manually update just your theme's `bundle.js` with the code from `bundle.js` Magento 1.8 *and* for the JSON object, in the file 'app/core/Mage/Bundle/Block/Catalog/Product/View/Type/Bundle.php', by inspection between 1.7 and 1.8,

Magento 1.7

```
//file app/core/Mage/Bundle/Block/Catalog/Product/View/Type/Bundle.php
//class Mage_Bundle_Block_Catalog_Product_View_Type_Bundle
//function getJsonConfig()
//...
                $tierPrices = $_selection->getTierPrice();
                foreach ($tierPrices as &$tierPriceInfo) {
                    $tierPriceInfo['price'] = $coreHelper->currency($tierPriceInfo['price'], false, false);
                }
                unset($tierPriceInfo); // break the reference with the last element
//...
```

Magento 1.8

```
//file app/core/Mage/Bundle/Block/Catalog/Product/View/Type/Bundle.php
//class Mage_Bundle_Block_Catalog_Product_View_Type_Bundle
//function getJsonConfig()
//...
                $tierPrices = $_selection->getTierPrice();
                foreach ($tierPrices as &$tierPriceInfo) {
                    $tierPriceInfo['price'] = $coreHelper->currency($tierPriceInfo['price'], false, false);
                    $tierPriceInfo['priceInclTax'] = $taxHelper->getPrice($_selection, $tierPriceInfo['price'], true);
                    $tierPriceInfo['priceExclTax'] = $taxHelper->getPrice($_selection, $tierPriceInfo['price']);
                }
                unset($tierPriceInfo); // break the reference with the last element
//...
```

So if you are manually updating an older version of Magento you will need to extend the class `Mage_Bundle_Block_Catalog_Product_View_Type_Bundle` and create your own new `bundle.php` with this updated `getJsonConfig()`

I have not run a diff between these files from 1.7 and 1.8 which would be worth doing to see if anything else has changed.

All this assumes you can get to the bottom of why you have tierPrice['32000-5'] so as I mentioned above, compare my bundle JSON object declaration with yours or paste yours here for others to inspect.

*What did we learn? I think you are using Magento 1.5. But even Magento 1.7 is not good enough. The features you are trying to use are not fully bug-fixed until Magento 1.8.*

Malachy.

Comment: Hi Malachy, thanks for the post - I actually figured out a fix that just involves changing the bundle.js file - it looks like it's a bit simpler than your suggestion - I will post it now.

Answer (score 0):

This is me answering my own question!

So I figured out why it wasn't working.  The Magento code tries to iterate through an object using:

```
var(i=0;i<object.length;i++)
```

This will not work for an object.  I changed the code to iterate through the object with a for (key in object) in the **selectionPrice: function(optionId, selectionId)** method:

```
if (this.config.priceType == '0') {
        price = this.config.options[optionId].selections[selectionId].price;
        tierPrice = this.config.options[optionId].selections[selectionId].tierPrice;

        // Ensures that tierPrice is set 
        // If a selection has no tier pricing it would return an empty array

        if (tierPrice.length != 0){

        // Iterate through tier Pricing until you reach correct quantity break
        // then set price.    

        for (key in tierPrice){
          if (tierPrice.hasOwnProperty(key)){
            if(tierPrice[key].price_qty <= qty && tierPrice[key].price <= price) {
                price = tierPrice[key].price;

            }
        }
        }
        }
```

Then at the bottom of the method you need to put the condition **tierPrice.length == 0** otherwise your tier pricing just gets overwritten again:

```
// Check that priceInclTax AND tierPrice are not set
    if (selection.priceInclTax !== undefined && tierPrice.length == 0) {

        priceInclTax = selection.priceInclTax;
        price = selection.priceExclTax !== undefined ? selection.priceExclTax : selection.price;

    }

    else {
        priceInclTax = price;
    }
```

This seems to do the trick for me - it now successfully updates the "Price as Configured" to account for tier pricing, and still updates all other pricing successfully too.  If you have a Magento store that has the weee module/tax rules then it might kick up a fuss, but for my store configuration it works great.

Hope that helps!

Comment: To help others that visit thia Q&A, what version of Magento is this fix for? Are you on 1.5? 1.6?

Comment: You may want to edit your for..in loop to use this syntax due to [Douglas Crockford](http://javascript.crockford.com/code.html) 

`     for (variable in object) {
        if (object.hasOwnProperty(variable)) {
            statements
        }
    }`

For the record the price including and excluding tax is not only related to WEEE it includes sales tax too, so this is a straightforward patch for tier prices that are not complicated by tax.

I think the best solution is to upgrade to Magento 1.8

Comment: Thanks for the heads-up on hasOwnProperty!  The patch works for me because we don't show tax until the checkout, so when you are on the bundle page you'll always see the price without any tax.  Upgrading to 1.8 is also a decent solution, but I'm still a little anxious about moving from 1.7.0.2 (my current version) in case anything breaks haha!

Comment: Wow. My code is actually 1.7.0.0. Did Magento make this bundle tier pricing worse before they made it better again?